# Project won't build unless reference lowercase

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, visual-studio-2015

I have a C# web application that's a mishmash of C# and VB.NET. I'm adding some features to it. I took it out of the mothballs, dusted it off and tried compiling it in VS2015. It gave me some reference errors. I fixed them by removing the assembly references and then just adding them back in. That worked; weird.

Looking at the project file differences, however, all I see are some GUIDs that have different cases. For example, this:

```
<ProjectReference Include="..\SomeControllers\SomeControllers.csproj">
  <Project>{D7423D79-0A59-4F9E-A142-863785821DF0}</Project>
  <Name>SomeControllers</Name>
</ProjectReference>
```

was changed to this:

```
<ProjectReference Include="..\SomeControllers\SomeControllers.csproj">
  <Project>{d7423d79-0a59-4f9e-a142-863785821df0}</Project>
  <Name>SomeControllers</Name>
</ProjectReference>
```

The only difference that I can see is that one is lowercase, the other is uppercase. The other difference is that the project compiles with the second GUID, not the first one.

One other mystery is that there are still plenty of GUIDs in the project files that are all uppercase, and they still compile. Can anyone explain this strange behavior?

Comment: I would try building the project using msbuild for both cases to see if it makes a difference. VS might be doing something funky to the project file whenever you play around with references.

Comment: @Peter4499: I wouldn't say that question has been _answered_, it was just a regex script to change all the GUIDs to uppercase (which is actually the opposite of my problem). Thanks anyway. I guess it's just a MSBuild bug...

Comment: @Frecklefoot just trying to help. If a woraround is not what you need then have a look at the solution file before it was re-added. See if that GUID appears anywhere else. When you open a solution file with a newer version of VS it sometimes converts it, if it converted so that the "new" references to the GUID were in lowercase or vice versa it could explain the issue. It wouldn't resolve but at least you have the root cause.